# Pass data to a store?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

How can I pass data from my vue component into a store?

Here's my component:

```
methods: {
    ...mapActions('NavBar', [
        'fix',
    ]),
    onClick: function() {
        this.fix('my-data');
    },
    ....
```

And on the store:

```
actions: {           
   fix: ({ commit }) => {
    //get data here?
   },
},
```

Comment: does it have to be an action (which could be asynchronous), or would a mutation (synchronous change to the store) work as well?

Comment: either is fine, although I would like to know for actions too for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actions as well as Mutations in VueJS 2.x can take one additional argument (often referred to as `payload`) with additional data.

From the [VueJS documentation on Mutations](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html):

> You can pass an additional argument to store.commit, which is called
>   the payload for the mutation:

```
mutations: {
  increment (state, n) {
    state.count += n
  }
}
store.commit('increment', 10)
```

> In most cases, the payload should be an object so that it can contain
>   multiple fields, and the recorded mutation will also be more
>   descriptive:

```
mutations: {
  increment (state, payload) {
    state.count += payload.amount
  }
}
store.commit('increment', {
  amount: 10
})
```

And for [Actions](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/actions.html):

> Actions support the same payload format and object-style dispatch:

```
// dispatch with a payload
store.dispatch('incrementAsync', {
  amount: 10
})

// dispatch with an object
store.dispatch({
  type: 'incrementAsync',
  amount: 10
})
```

The documentation seems not very clear on how to define the action, but it looks like the following should work:

```
actions: {
  incrementAsync ({ commit, state }, payload) { ... }
}
```